# How to change ol bullets for clickable images

Tags: html, css

I have the ordered list:

```
<ol>
    <li>Text1</li>
    <li>Text2</li>
</ol>
```

, and i want to replace bullets for clickable images. I know how to replace bullets for images, but i need **clickable** images.

My current implementation:

Html:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <div class="button speaker"></div>
        Text1
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="button speaker"></div>
        Text2
    </li>
</ol>
```

Css:

```
.button {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    position: relative;
    left: -30px;
    top: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}

.speaker {
    background-image: url(../images/navbuttons/btn_speaker.png);
}
```

How it looks now:

[image]

What i want:

[image]

IE 9, 10, 11 bugs:

[image]

It is working in FireFox and Chrome, but is not working in IE. Also i'm looking for a simple and useful solution.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/alexmac/mvjeD/)

Comment: "Not working in IE" define how.

Comment: please check this link : http://www.techforluddites.com/2014/01/replacing-list-bullets-with-images-using-css.html

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol, i've added IE bug screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried using a span instead of a div?

Comment: @Paulie_D, yes i've tried. In this case images is not displayed.

Comment: Have you tried `list-style: none` on the `ol`?

Comment: ol, li { list-style: none; }

Comment: @Alex and @Artem Fitiskin, yes `list-style: none;` is working. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switched out the div for a span (although an anchor link would probably be better if it's clickable)

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/h6uyc/2/)

**HTML**

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <span class="button speaker"></span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem dolores magnam labore voluptate vero corporis pariatur neque temporibus magni soluta commodi molestias ducimus explicabo minima!
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="button speaker"></span>
        Text2
    </li>
</ol
```

> 

**CSS**

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    line-height:25px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: -30px;
}

.button {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.speaker {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-25-25-10.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove numbers in IE just add css:

```
ol{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

To make images clickable change html like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="button speaker"></div>
    </a>
    Text1
</li>
```

For each li.
[JsFIDDLE Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mvjeD/2/)

Or you can use js:

```
$('.speaker').unbind('click').click(function(){
window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com'; // as example
return false;
```

});

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mvjeD/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I have added the ol to the styling and used CSS to add the image and HTML to make the image a link.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#"><ol></a>
<li>
    <div class="button speaker"></div>
    Text1
</li>
<li>
    <div class="button speaker"></div>
    Text2
</li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
cursor: pointer;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
position: relative;
left: -30px;
top: 25px;
height: 25px;
width: 25px;
}

.speaker {
background-image: url(../images/navbuttons/btn_speaker.png);
} 

ol
{
list-style-image("img src");
}
```